# how to add admin with devise in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, admin

I am using devise gem and i wanna to create admin

rails g migration add_admin_to_user

in the db

```
 def change
    add_column :users, :admin , :boolean , {default: false}
  end
```

def user

```
def admin?
    user=User.create(email: "info@presale.ca",password: "12345678")
    user.admin=true
    user
    user.save
    admin
  end
end
```

in the index page

```
<% if current_user && current_user.admin? %>
<% end %>
```

theres something wrong in the def user how to fix it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things that aren't ideal:

1. Your attribute `User.admin` is a boolean, which means without adding a method in User.rb (model), you will be able to do `User.admin?` and it will return true or false.
2. It's not a good idea to create your admin user in your method that checks if the current user is an admin. The quickest way is to go into rails console (via your terminal) and updating a User to admin = true, e.g. `User.last.update_attribute(:admin, true)`.

Comment: If I want to add it in the model not in the concle how can i do it

Answer (score 1):

Because you already have a boolean :admin attribute on your User model, there's a default `admin?` method out of the box. If you call something like `User.find(1).admin?` it will return true or false based on your value in your db - so you probably don't want to override this.

Define a new method in your User model to assign the admin attribute.

```
def make_admin!
  self.update_attribute(:admin, true)
end
```

Now you can call `User.find(1).make_admin!` in your controller, or in rails console, or wherever you have a User instance.

Then you can change the code in your view to this:

```
<% if user_signed_in? && current_user.admin? %>
  # Show Admin Stuff
<% end %>
```

Comment: How to call this User.find(1).make_admin! in controller?

Comment: 1. Generate a new controller named admins. 2. Define an action named make_admin in this controller. 3. Set an instance variable for your user via @user = current_user, then call @user.make_admin!. 3. In routes.rb, define a route called `post 'make_admin', to: 'admins#make_admin'`. Now if you send a post request to this route it will update your current user. That's just one of many possibilities.