# Ruby on Rails 5 devise custom fields not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am having a problem with devise custom field  Ruby on Rails 5.0.  I am using devise to handle user account maintenance.  I have successfully added a custom field called admin_user to my user model.  This field is a Boolean field.  I create a session variable to hold whether the user is an admin user in a callback function in my application controller.
The idea is that when a user logs in if they are admin user they will see the admin menu.  If they are an ordinary user they won't.  This doesn't seem to work.  I am concerned that the database is  not storing admin user as a boolean field.  The value shows up as t or f in the database so I dont know if that means they value is a text value or it is actually a boolean.
No matter what I try the following doesn't work.  The system seems to think that all the user are not admin users.  Would anyone have any ideas as to what is wrong.
Based on the following what I'm doing should be correct:
[how to add admin with devise in ROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820760/how-to-add-admin-with-devise-in-ror)

[Set a session variable in devise on sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422910/set-a-session-variable-in-devise-on-sign-in)

Could I use the ruby code current_user.admin_user? instead.  I've tried this already but unfortunately it didn't work.
If anyone could help or even point me in the right direction I'd be very greatful.
HTML

```
<% if session[:admin_usr]  %> 
  <div id="adminMenu" name="adminMenu" class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Admin</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="/brands">Brand</a>
      <a href="/products">Product</a>
      <a href="/categories">Category</a>
    </div>
  </div>
<% else %> 
  <div id="profileMenu" name="profileMenu" class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Profile</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="/addresses">Addresses</a>
      <a href="/payments">Payments</a>
      <a href="/payments">Orders</a>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Partial Database Table Listing

```
id = 1
email = asas.com
admin_user = t

id = 2
email = s@s.com
admin_user = f
```

Database Table listing

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             null: false
    **t.boolean  "admin_user",             default: false**
    t.integer  "addresses_id"
    t.integer  "sales_orders_id"
    t.integer  "payments_id"
    t.index ["addresses_id"], name: "index_users_on_addresses_id"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["payments_id"], name: "index_users_on_payments_id"
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
    t.index ["sales_orders_id"], name: "index_users_on_sales_orders_id"
  end
```

Controller Code

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  # GET /categories
  # GET /categories.json
  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end
  before_filter :load_initial_data

 protected
  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    session[:admin_usr] = current_user.admin_user
    user_path(resource)
  end
  def load_initial_data
    @categories = Category.all
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm very sorry Folks After I wrote the question a possible solution dawned on me.  I should have tested this before I posted, but perhaps if I had not posted the question I would not have found the solution. Using the following code fixes the problem.  It also means I don't need the callback method in the application controller.  I guess on the positive side, writing the problem out helped me solve it.  I hope by posting this here that it helps others.

```
<% if current_user.admin_user %>
  <div id="adminMenu" name="adminMenu" class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Admin</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="/brands">Brand</a>
      <a href="/products">Product</a>
      <a href="/categories">Category</a>
    </div>
  </div>
 <% else %> 
  <div id="profileMenu" name="profileMenu" class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Profile</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="/addresses">Addresses</a>
      <a href="/payments">Payments</a>
      <a href="/payments">Orders</a>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```